# How to omit a data range with no filtering

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I have the following bar chart in `dc.js`
[image: barChart]
Built with

```
.dimension(dimPreparation).group(grpPreparation).x(d3.scale.ordinal())
.xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
```

The `dimPreparation` is also used by other graphs. I'd like to hide the rightmost part of this graph, as only the first examples are of interest (those with, say, x>10), and with it increase the readability, but I can't filter because it will change the other plots. I thought I could do this changing the `xUnits`, but I've now spent quite some time with no success. Is it possible?

Comment: You can use .domain([]) to limit the range of an axis e.g .x(d3.time.scale().domain([minDate,maxDate]));  But will it need to be a dynamic range or static?

Comment: In this case, with an ordinal scale, it would be `.domain([0,1,2,4,5,6,7])`, say. Another option, if that doesn't work, would be creating a [fake group](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#fake-groups) for this chart, that truncates the results of `group.all()`. This is similar to what the cap mixin does (although the cap mixin is not available for bar charts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @gordon mentioned, from [here](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#fake-groups), it is possible to create a filtered group.

```
grpFiltered = filterPreparation(grpPreparation);
function(grpPreparation) {
    return {
        all: function() {
            return grp.all().filter(function(d) {
                return d.key <=10;
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Then use the `grpFiltered` instead.